# Confirmation of SQL statement disappeared

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, sqlplus

Until today after every SQL statement eg. `CREATE user t identified by t;` I had a confirmation of the execution `"User created."` Now I have nothing (no confirmation) but if I check if the user exists it is positive:

```
select username from all_users where username='T';

USERNAME
--------
T
```

How to turn it on again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the feedback on SQL*Plus is set to off then you don't get the confirmation messages.

```
SQL> set feedback off
SQL> create user c##u1 identified by user1;
```

set feedback on.

```
SQL> set feedback on
SQL> drop user c##u1;

User dropped.

SQL> create user c##u1 identified by user1;

User created.
```

**Documentation:** [SET FEEDBACK](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#SQPUG079)

Comment: Thanks for an answer! Is there a similar variable for displaying feedback from a script? Cause right now I have feedbacks from simple statements but when I run some script it is still missing.

Comment: You can define the feedback, as you have done, in the script as well.